# I used uDraper plugins in source edition UE5,tips build through you IDE

Tags: c++

I used Draper in Source Edition UE5(release version UE4.24 and UE5.0.3 works correctly ), operated 1,2, and 3 according to ReadMe in the installation path, and also replaced BuildId. However, when I opened the project tips :  build through you IDE

I get an error when I don't follow the README:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sljw0.png)

ReadMe Info:
uDraper plugin is distributed in a binary form (without source code).
There where some undocumented but well known ways to achieve this without breaking the build of C++ projects in UE4.
But in UE5 it seems not to be the case anymore (there are plenty of complaints about this issue on the Internet).
At this point we can suggest a somwhat hacky way to make your C++ projects work properly in the presence of uDraper plugin:

1. Copy UnrealBuildTool.DraperHook.* files into [UE5 Root]\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool
2. Replace "UnrealBuildTool.exe" with "UnrealBuildTool.DraperHook.dll" in [UE5 Root]\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat
3. replace "UnrealBuildTool.exe" with "UnrealBuildTool.DraperHook.exe" in [UE5 Root]\Engine\Config\BaseEngine.ini ("UnrealBuildTool" value under "PlatformPaths" section)

It's still a work in progress so we hope to find a better solution in the future.

Regarding custom Engine builds we expect that the binary distribution of the uDraper plugin should be compatible as long as ABI didn't change.
Just replace "BuildId" in Draper\Binaries\Win64\UnrealEditor.modules to your "CompatibleChangelist" from [UE5 Root]\Engine\Build\Build.version

step 1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWcNY.png)

step 2:   The original file says "UnrealBuildTool.dll" not "UnrealBuildTool.exe"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLlcw.png)

step 3:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL7fD.png)

The above modification is still the error of FIG. 1

step 4:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5bxd.png)

open project
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4JOv.png)

I opened the project with VS and compiled it successfully, and opened it again with the same erro.Previously, the plug-in was placed in the project path to open the project promptFailed to generate Projiect files,

Answer (score 0):

We try to keep uDraper plugin up to date with official UE releases and do not attempt to support custom builds from GitHub.
The instructions you're referring to might be helpful but we do not guarantee that it will work with any GitHub version.
You can try to find an earlier UE version on GitHub to better match an officially released version and try it out.